# why my sub menu is not working in html css

Tags: html, css

I have created my nav bar which was working fine but now i tried to add sub menu in my navbar and its not showing sub menu on hover. kindly check and correct me.

First I added `<ul>` in my `<li>` tag then I added css to hide nested `<ul>` then I tried to show `<ul>` on hover `<li>`

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


nav{
  background-color: red;
}

ul{

  background-color: purple;
  width: 50%; 
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;   
}
nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
font: bold 12px Arial;      
}

nav ul li:hover{
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
}

nav ul li:hover a{

  color: red;
}

ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="">About Us</a></li>
        <li> <a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li> <a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Submenu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Submenu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @0stone0 how to add this Run Code Snippet ?

Comment: there is special code-editor [button in the toolbar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/5625547)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `<li>` wrap is incorrect!

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/k9qyLvoj/8/)

After `Privacy Policy` you have created another `<li>` that shouldn't be needed. you have to wrap the sub-menus with in `privacy policy` tag not a new one that is one of the reason why the css was not showing data as expected and you were almost there regarding `CSS` I just fixed it for you! hope it helps.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 30px;
}

nav ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: if you dropdown issue is solved but its not showing sub menu exactly below the its parent link i mean Privacy policy link

Comment: you need exactly below to the parent li?

Comment: @barbiequeen I have added fiddle and fixed the issue in SO UI as well. let me know.

Comment: wow its working. did you add just top:30px ? or you have changed something else too which effects ?

Comment: Nope, the SO UI and fiddler has border differences I assume, I just added this `* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}` nothing else.

Comment: @barbiequeen yeah I know, I was modifying your code during that time, I didnt see that. If the answer helped you then would you mind accepting it as answer and voting if it is worth!

Comment: thanks. the question you asked in SO you mean? if so yeah.

Comment: ok but dun know why some flagged my question voted in negative so i cant ask again,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210668/discussion-between-manjuboyz-and-barbiequeen).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start from this working snippet and try to change data according to your needs :)

[HTML Sub-Nav](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_subnav)

Comment: excellent i just tried to learn byself. i dun want to just copy paste thats why

Answer (score 0):

```css
   *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


nav{
    background-color: red;
}

ul{

    background-color: purple;
    width: 50%; 
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;   
}
nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
font: bold 12px Arial;      
}

nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: blue;
    color: red;
}

nav ul li:hover a{

    color: red;
}

ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
    <li> <a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">About Us</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="">test</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu 4</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
        

</ul>
```

Comment: css is same as mine, what you have changed ? just added <a> after <li> ?

Comment: i changed the html and you should add a link for sub menu.

Comment: heheh what a stupid mistake by me. thanks, now its not showing exactly below that link but litle bit more left and upword.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an anchor tag in the sub nav you have created. Because currently those sub-tabs are created but are not associated with any super-tab.

`<a href="">Subnav</a>`

So add this above your sub-nav code. You are good to go.